# Elasticsearch Aggregation Scope Issue

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an Elasticsearch Index with more than **100 Millions** of records.

If I run below query then response comes (1 record) within **1 second**

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must":{
                "term": {
                "_id": "a36403af960840b86452bf1a6bd42fde3b4773e0"
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

But if I run below query then response comes in more than **2 minutes.**

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must":{
                "term": {
                "_id": "a36403af960840b86452bf1a6bd42fde3b4773e0"
                }
            }

        }
    },

    "aggs": {
        "mywordcloud": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "post.content_terms"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know why it is taking so much time after adding aggregation on the top of the query where _id = a36403af960840b86452bf1a6bd42fde3b4773e0 which matches with only 1 record.

As per my assumption elastic search is applying aggregation on the output of the data. So technically it should run aggregation on 1 record and response must come within 1 second too almost same as without using aggs.

How to fix this issue?

I am using Elastic Search Version **1.5**

Comment: why don't you upgrade to latest 5.3 which has lot of improvements and then check the results and response time.

Comment: I am planning to upgrade but not sure if it will fix aggs scope issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's a good example where you need to consider choosing `filter` context over `query` context.

Try running the same query using `filter` as shown below:

```
GET my-index/_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter":{
                "term": {
                "_id": "a36403af960840b86452bf1a6bd42fde3b4773e0"
                }
            }

        }
    },

    "aggs": {
        "mywordcloud": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "post.content_terms"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> My first suggestion

is that to upgrade :-
I have tried your second query in 1.7.2 , it very fast . I think upgradation will definitely solve your issue .

> Second suggestion
>   Not sure it will work with Elastic Search Version 1.5 .

try this query :-

```
{
    "query": {
        "constant_score": {
            "filter":{
                "term": {
                "_id": "a36403af960840b86452bf1a6bd42fde3b4773e0"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "mywordcloud": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "post.content_terms"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

OR

```
 {
        "aggregations": {
            "bylife": {
                "terms": {
                    "field": "post.content_terms"
                },
                "aggregations": {
                    "bylife2": {
                        "filter": {
                            "term": {
                                "_id": "a36403af960840b86452bf1a6bd42fde3b4773e0"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I know this will give different data , but u can change your logic with this approach .